# Converting collection to array with no extra memory

Tags: java, arrays, performance, memory, collections

I need to convert Map into 2D array, so I've wrote this piece of code but it eats a lot of memory and I can't figure out why.

```
private DataItem[][] convertDataToArrays(boolean[] filter,
                                         Map<Integer, List<T>> dataSet)                           
        double[] data = new double[sizeOfNewVector];
        DataItem[][] reducedData = new DataItem[dataSet.size()][];
        for (int i = dataSet.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            reducedData[i] = new DataItem[dataSet.get(i).size()];
            for (int j = reducedData[i].length - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
                reducedData[i][(reducedData[i].length - 1) - j] = new DataItem(data);
                dataSet.get(i).remove(j);
            }
            dataSet.remove(i);
        }
        return reducedData;
```

here is DataItem class:

```
public class DataItem {

    public double[] data;

    public DataItem(double[] data) {
        this.data = new double[data.length];
        System.arraycopy(data, 0, this.data, 0, data.length);
    }
}
```

What algorithm should do:

1. take last element from list
2. copy it.
3. delete element from list
4. store copy into new 2D array
5. repeat until list is empty

this should go for all lists in map.

Problem is, that step 3. just leave element and doesn't shrink the array, so when I insert a huge dataset in convert method, I've got java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded

I need to do it without any extra memory. Can anyone help me, please?

EDIT:

I am using ArrayList and HashMap.

Comment: Why you need to copy `DataItem` objects if you remove originals? Just copy the references into the resulting array. Please specify how big the `dataSet` in your case (roughly how many `DataItem` objects you have in total).

Comment: I've removed one inner loop where I modify "data".  It can be shorter vector. It is not important for my question and I didn't want to confuse people here.

Comment: You will always need *some* extra memory for the process. I don't know, which collections you are using for `Map` and `List`, but *every* type will shrink the size at some point (although not immediately). `HashMap` and `ArrayList` will probably take longer than, let's say, `TreeMap` and `LinkedList`, but in change `LinkedList` has a considerable memory overhead to start with. I think your problem is really that you are working very, very close to the memory limit. If you are not able to pay for that overhead here and get away with it somehow, it will bite you somewhere else.

Comment: I've edited what collection I use. That's strange, I should have like 1 Gb free (consider my dataset has 4 Gb)

Comment: Another thing: Are you sure that step 3 is your problem? Since the main chunk of your data seems to be within those big `DataItem` objects, it would be really strange that just the list that references them is the problem. Are you sure that you are not duplicating those `DataItem` objects here and still have a reference to the old ones somewhere else, so in the end you created 2 copies of the data?

Comment: MAT is a useful project to analyze *where* your memory actually goes, check it out: http://www.eclipse.org/mat/

Comment: Thank you @mastov I will check that. But still, when GC is hit, shouldn't it erase all removed elements and not just throw OutOfMemory? In memory complexity there shouldn't be problem.

Comment: The GC can only remove *objects* (!) that are *unreachable*. If it really turns out that your `ArrayList` is the problem (I don't think so), then the `ArrayList` keeps an array that is too big. There's nothing the GC can do about it because the array is still *reachable* (from the `ArrayList`) and the GC can only discard the *whole object* (i.e. the whole array).

Comment: In case that I'm right and you have 2 copies of all the `DataItem` objects, then there is nothing the GC can do about it because all those objects are still reachable: 1 copy of each via your new 2D array and 1 copy of each via some place else where you still have references to the old objects. I don't know, if that's the case, but given the data structure it sounds far more likely than the `List` being the culprit. Note also that `remove` will remove an item from the list, but if that item is still referenced from another place, it won't get deleted until those other references are removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your theory is entirely possible. It does take the `ArrayList` a while to shrink the size of the internal array used to store the references. You can avoid that effect by using another `List` implementation like `LinkedList` that doesn't show this behavior, but those also have considerable memory overhead that might eat up the space you saved.

That being said, given your data structure I find it highly unlikely that just the overhead of some additional references in `ArrayList` pushes your memory need over the top. I find it much more likely that you are creating copies of all your, apparently relatively big (judging from the array inside), objects of type `DataItem`. If someone else still has references to the original `DataItem` objects, your call to `remove` will remove their *references* from the list, but the *objects themselves* stay alive until *all* references to them are removed.

I'd recommend checking your memory footprint, with a smaller example that actually works, using something like the [MAT tool](http://www.eclipse.org/mat/). See how many objects of type `DataItem` you have *before* and *after* the conversion. If they increased, my theory was right and you should avoid that problem by either not copying the *objects*, but just their *references* (if you can), or by getting rid of the additional references to the old objects. If my theory was wrong, check which part of the memory increases most to identify the culprit.